# Logistic regression with categorical variable as a response variable

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am trying to put a categorical variable as a response variable to glm function.
So I initially did this:

```
logreg_ <- glm(Genre ~ price, data = train)
msummary(logreg_)
```

However, it just have given this as a result and I don't know how to fix this.

```
Error in y - mu : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

The glimpse() of these columns are like this:

```
$ Genre            <chr> "Strategy", "Strategy", "Early Access", "Early Access",~
$ price            <dbl> 0.00, 0.79, 3.99, 11.39, 5.59, 0.79, 10.99, 5.79, 1.69,~
```

What should I do?

Comment: It looks like you need to switch Genre and price.  The formula specification is `glm( y ~ x, data)`  So try `logreg_ <- glm(price ~ Genre , data = train)`

Comment: Would it still do the same thing as a result?

Comment: No, sorry I misread your question, that would predict price based on Genre.  To predict a categorical variable based on a numeric, you probably need to go to other methods. The first one that occurs is to use a logistic regression, which can predict true/false values.  You would want to recode your data so you had a column for each of your categories, then use `glm(category ~ price, data = train, family = "binomial")`.  Probably need to verify that this is appropriate for your case.

Comment: You probably need **multinomial regression**, see questions on this site (e.g. `nnet::multinom()`

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Brian , for logistic regression, you need to specify `glm(...,family="binomial)`, second the outcome must be a `factor`. A toy example:

```
set.seed(4)
df <- data.frame(y =sample(letters[1:4],100,replace = T),x=runif(100),stringAsFactor=T)
str(df)
logreg<- glm(y ~ x, data = df,family = "binomial")
summary(logreg)
```

Comment: I have tried family="binomial" and did as.factor(train$Genre) before running the regression, but now it gives the error [Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1]

Comment: I hope you did `train$Genre <- as.factor(train$Genre)` or at least `glm(as.factor(Genre)~.,data=train, familiy="binomial")` If this doesn't work for you (which would be really odd) try to recode your outcome in 0-1 like `train$Genre <- ifelse(train$Genre=="strategy",1,0)` if strategy is your reference. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942910/logistic-regression-evalfamilyinitialize-y-values-must-be-0-y-1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546658/logistic-regression-on-factor-error-in-evalfamilyinitialize-y-values-must) for solutions of your identical problem